# HFile creation - Added a key not lexically larger than previous key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a program that creates Put files -

```
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.add(someKey));
    put.add(COLUMN_FAMILY, colName, timeStamp, dataByteArr); 
    return put;
```

I am trying to create Hfiles for these Puts using the following code.

```
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(baseDir + "/" + childInputDir + "*"));

    job.setInputFormatClass(TolerantSequenceFileInputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(KeyPutImporter.class);
    HTable htable = new HTable(conf, tableName);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);

    HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, htable);
    Path hfileOutputPath = new Path(baseDir + "/" + childOutputDir);
    HFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, hfileOutputPath);

    TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job.getConfiguration(), com.google.common.base.Preconditions.class);

    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

While creating the HFiles, I get the following exception.

```
    java.io.IOException: Added a key not lexically larger than previous key=
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.checkKey(HFile.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.append(HFile.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.append(HFile.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer.reduce(PutSortReducer.java:72)
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

When using the bulkloader (LoadIncrementalHFiles, doBulkLoad) you can only add items that are "lexically ordered", ie. you need to make sure that the items you add are sorted by the row-id.